# Binding ObservableCollection to DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am binding an observable collection (FoodList) to a BindingSource in my WinForm. This BindingSource is used by a datagrid on the form. I had assumed that when I added a new item to the collection it would raise an event and a new row would show up in my grid. This does not happen though.

```
namespace Foods
{
    public class FoodList : ObservableCollection<Food>
    {

    }
}

private void frmFoods_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        foodSource = new Source("Foods.xml");
        foodBindingSource.DataSource = foodSource.Foods;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}

private void AddFood()
{
    using (frmFood frm = new frmFood())
    {
        frm.ShowDialog(this);
        if (!frm.Canceled)
        {
            foodSource.Foods.Add(frm.Food);     // <-- No new row.
            //foodBindingSource.ResetBindings(false);
            foodDataGridView.ClearSelection();
            foodDataGridView.CurrentCell = foodDataGridView[0, foodDataGridView.Rows.Count - 1];
            foodDataGridView.Focus();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I added a listener to the form for the foodSource.Foods observable collection and it DID fire an add event. Maybe the DataGridView in WinForms does not support ObservableCollections? I know MS is really pushing WPF, maybe this is a WPF only feature?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723041/a-good-collection-to-use-when-binding-to-a-datagridview-in-c-sharp).ObservableCollection<T> won't work for a DataGridView : it implements INotifyCollectionChanged, not IBindingList, and the DataGridView doesn't know about INotifyCollectionChanged. It is intended for WPF bindings and is not used in Windows Forms.

Answer (score 17):

`ObservableCollection<T>` doesn't work with WinForms controls.

However [`BindingList<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679(v=vs.110).aspx) will work the way you expect.