# Winform with backgroundworker

Tags: c#, winforms, tcp

I have C# winform being tcp server. the message receiving function runs with backgroundworker.

My winform will display a datagridview, which links to a bindingList of Objects like:

```
ClientObject {
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string ip { get; set; }
    public int port { get; set; }
}
```

And when the server receives message, it will update the bindingList sometimes, and refresh the datagridview. My problem is, the winform sometimes hangs, and when I run the winform with debug mode in Visual Studio, the backgroundworker is still running.

Does the update bindingList part causes the winform to hang? Should I use mutex or something when I update the bindingList?

Thanks for help.

PS. I have `Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;` at the beginning

Comment: Never use `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls  = false`

Comment: `ObservableCollection` is what you are looking for to update. as `ObservableCollection<ClientObject>` better for binding and update at the end

Comment: Does ObservableCollection work with datagridview? I tried and did some searching http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723041/a-good-collection-to-use-when-binding-to-a-datagridview-in-c-sharp

Comment: By the way will this modification affect the performance of tcp server?